# How to calculate completely position-based gradients on an image？

Tags: python, image, image-processing

[image: example image]I have known the Laplace or sobel operators, but these operations are performed on the gray values in the image. Is there a similarly simple way available to calculate the slope/curvature of a point on circle or some other graph for that graph?

If possible, I'd like this approach to rely as little as possible on grayscale information (just whether or not something is in the outline) .
In addition, whether this method can rely less on neighborhood connectivity, because a possible contour width is not composed of a single pixel.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I added a simple example image in a later edit

Comment: @YvesDaoust My description may not be accurate enough, but I want to be able to get the slope of an image at a certain point as if I were doing geometry on paper. For example, in my geometry, I want to be able to make a tangent to a point on the edge and get a slope, where the gradient is based on geometry rather than grayscale

Comment: Are you aware that due to the discretization, the direction of the tangent is quite uncertain ?

Comment: You did not answer this: "If the contours are thick, where should the "gradient" be evaluated ?"

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've read a bit about rasterization before, and I know about the information loss from a vectorized line to a pixel, and I'm guessing there might be an inverse rasterization-like operation? As for the problem you mentioned, is the solution I'd like to have instead of multi-pixel represented by a single pixel, or is it will be a way to get the pixels from the outermost point?

Comment: In the future my work will require some kind of contour fitting, so I need to get the points on the edges and their gradient information (for building my algorithm, perhaps B-spline or polynomial interpolation) , and getting the gradient information (the first or second derivative) helps me to test some of my research conjectures

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think this is an XY problem, I know that spline fitting only needs a few points of coordinate and I've tried it (and it works really well) , but I also need the gradients of these sampling points for some additional evaluation and research (I want to look for patterns at some statistical level with this information，and I think there's some hidden mechanism in the contouring process that can be identified statistically) , as I said earlier:point for curve fitting and gradient for follow-up research

Comment: No, I'm serious.  The spline API I use outputs discrete point set so I didn't even think about it, I subconsciously thought Its ok but i should even construct a spline curve with mostly point on the image as input if I want to getderivative anywhere.Because the actual image may be more complex I did not try.My original question was to find an existing simple get point-connect line-calculate derivative strategy,I'm not sure that the increased budget burden of this obvious approach is worth its increased precision.Maybe I can rewrite my spline function code to try it out,thk for waste time on me

Comment: oh "it" in the " is worth its increased precision" means spline method,As for the final selection of splines or interpolation, it is too early for me, now at least I should try to get derivative after making local fitting of the curve rather than connect line for every point i need